# How to find the difference in tokens in two strings using Unix tools?

Tags: utilities, string

I have two strings as below-

```
token1, token2, token3, token4, token5, token6, token8, token9, token10

token2, token7, token4, token3, token5, token6, token8, token10, token9
```

Visually, I can see that "tokens" like `token1` and `token7` are not present in both strings. But is there an easy way to get the differing tokens using Unix tools?

The long route would be to write a script and maintain a hashmap of {token => count} and in the end print only those keys that have count = 1. But I suppose there is a shorter way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNUly:

```
s1='token1, token2, token3, token4, token5, token6, token8, token9, token10'
s2='token2, token7, token4, token3, token5, token6, token8, token10, token9'
comm <(grep -oE '\w+' <<< "$s1" | sort) <(grep -oE '\w+' <<< "$s2" | sort)
```

Gives:

```
token1
                token10
                token2
                token3
                token4
                token5
                token6
        token7
                token8
                token9
```

The columns are:

1. tokens only in s1
2. tokens only in s2
3. tokens in both.

You suppress a column by passing the corresponding option (like `-3` to suppress the 3rd column).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below.

```
cat input1 input2 >> output
arr=$(cat output | tr "," "\n")
echo "${arr[@]}" | tr ' ' '\n' | sort -u | tr '\n' ' '
```

**Explanation**

I am merging the 2 files together into another file and splitting the tokens with comma as a delimiter. After that I am printing only the values that are unique (meaning only the values that occur once which I believe is what you are looking for).

*input1 file contents*

```
token1, token2, token3, token4, token5, token6, token8, token9, token10
```

*input2 file contents*

```
token2, token7, token4, token3, token5, token6, token8, token10, token9
```

After I execute the above script, I get the output as,

```
token1 token10 token2 token3 token4 token5 token6 token7 token8 token9
```

If you observe the above output, it would print only the unique values from both the files.

If you however need the difference alone, you can use the below command.

```
echo ${arr[@]} | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 1):

Pinching the basic idea from Ramesh

With GNU `awk` in `bash`

```
awk -v RS='[[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*' '{x[$0]++}; END{for (y in x) if (x[y] == 1) print y}'  
<(printf "%s" 'token1, token2, token3, token4, token5, token6, token8, token9, token10')  
<(printf "%s" 'token2, token7, token4, token3, token5, token6, token8, token10, token9')
token1
token7
```

Comment: I still have to make it print only the different values :) Trying to find out how to do it :)